# Get attached USB device information in Xamarin (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, usb

I am working on an android application. I have to detect when a new USB device is connected to the android device. For this I am using the **UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached** event. When I run my android application, I have to get the information of attached USB devices, I am doing that with the following code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);
    var DeviceList = manager.DeviceList;
    foreach (var device in DeviceList.Values)
    {
        var Class = device.Class;
        var DeviceClass = device.DeviceClass;
        var DeviceId = device.DeviceId;
        var DeviceName = device.DeviceName;
        var DeviceProtocol = device.DeviceProtocol;
        var DeviceSubClass = device.DeviceSubclass;
        var Type = device.GetType();
        var ManufacturerName = device.ManufacturerName;
        var ProductId = device.ProductId;
        var ProductName = device.ProductName;
        var SerialNumber = device.SerialNumber;
        var VendorId = device.VendorId;
        var Version = device.Version;
   }
}
```

Above code gives me information of all the USB devices attached to the android. While my application is running, if any USB device gets attached to the android device I have to trigger an event. Code for this is:

```
public class BroacastReceiverSystem : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public BroacastReceiverSystem() { }
    public event EventHandler usbAttached;
    public override void OnReceive(Context c, Intent i)
    {
        usbAttached(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

And the code where I am using the above code is:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);

    BroacastReceiverSystem usbReciever = new BroacastReceiverSystem();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached);
    RegisterReceiver(usbReciever, filter);
    usbReciever.usbAttached += usbAttachedSlot;
}
```

And the subscribed event definition is:

```
private void usbAttachedSlot(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

This code works fine, whenever I connect a new USB device to the android, code does detect that a new USB device is connected. But my issue is that I also want the information of the attached USB device, similar to the information which I get when the USB device is already connected before starting the android application. How can I get the information of newly connected USB device?

Comment: Hey there...
Did you have anything new on that issue?